# Changing directories in Windows command prompt

Tags: windows, cmd

I keep getting the message, 'YourFolder is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file', in Windows Command Prompt and Powershell. I want to set git up, upload my Android project to github.

YourFolder, though, definitely exists.

[image]

For example: Users folder exists.

But I try go into the Users folder and I get:
[image]

It happens with every single folder. I tried a few things like adding C:\Windows\System32\; into the environment variable and rebooting, and opening Command Prompt with Administrator Privileges but had no luck. Still the same problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the folder?  In the command prompt, you can't just run a folder name as a command like you can in explorer; you have to say what you want to do with it.  The command to change directories is `cd YourFolder`, and the command to open it in explorer is `start YourFolder`

Comment: I want to change the current working directory to my local project: C:\Users\Chris\AndroidStudioProjects\OMGAndroid. Then I'll be able to initialize the git repository.

Comment: This is not a programming question and so is off topic on SO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't run a folder name in the command prompt like you can in explorer; you have to tell the shell what you want to do with it.

If you want to to change directories to the console, use `cd YourFolder`

```
C:\>cd users

C:\Users>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.

 Directory of C:\Users

2014-07-17  17:47    <DIR>          .
2014-07-17  17:47    <DIR>          ..
etc
```

If you want to open an explorer window, the command is `start YourFolder`

Comment: Yep, that's it. It's been a while since I used the console panel (in Ubuntu mostly) and I forogt about that cd part before the folder name. Will accept answer when I'm allowed (5 more mins!)